# Unable to upgrade from HDP 2.3.4.0 to 2.3.4.7

Tags: upgrade, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to upgrade HDP 2.3.4.0 to HDP 2.3.4.7 version but I am getting below error message.

> stderr:   /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-676.txt 
>   2017-01-07 16:40:07,949 - Package Manager failed to install packages. Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install '--disablerepo=HDP-*' --enablerepo=HDP-2.3.4.7,HDP-UTILS-2.3.4.7 rpcbind' returned 1. Transaction check error:
>     package rpcbind-0.2.0-38.el7.x86_64 is already installed

Please find the link [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/storage/attachments/11221-error-log1.txt) for detailed error summary. I have registered the target version but while performing package installation, I am facing this issue. Please find the attached screen shots for your reference.

[Ambari-Stack-Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUs1S.png)

Could you please help on this.

Thank you.

BR, Sampath

Comment: Can you temporarily uninstall the *rpcbind* package just before the upgrade? If that would trigger complete removal of HDP, is it acceptable to perform clean installation instead of doing upgrade? Consider filing a bug report to HDP developers, as the installer should not require the dependencies to be missing beforehand.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I have removed the rpcbind package and tried to upgrade the HDP, it worked for me.